# Structured data for “carousel” snippet in Google Search: is it necessary to make "ItemList" the root element?

Tags: google-search, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I make a structured data of the category page on which the list of articles is displayed. It is necessary that when searching in Google this list is displayed as a "carousel".

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings - here is the documentation for marking the "carousel" with screenshots.

Is it necessary to make `ItemList` the root element in the markup structure?

Can an `ItemList` be made a child of a `CollectionPage` element? That is, as follows:

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CollectionPage">
  <div itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
  ...
```

Will the Google search engine understand the “`CollectionPage` > `ItemList` (`mainEntity`)” structure as a correct structure for the carousel?

Comment: I would suspect it is fine. All pages are assumed to be a top level of WebPage or a sub type. See what the Structured Data Testing Tool shows. And later check the Structured Data report in the Google Search Console.

Answer (score 1):

as a @unor says - the easiest way is to test this structure in Testing Tool: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool.

Your code has 
0 ERRORS
0 WARNINGS